# Java: Extract text from PDF and shows as header and items seperate array list

Tags: java, arrays, pdfbox

I am using PDFBOX and reading and saving the contents from PDF file . Requirement is text should be splitted to Header and Item in seperate array list .

PDF looks below.

[image]

Expected :

Following details PO,DeliveryDate,Vendor no should shown in arraylist 1 and other details like barcode,item number,description,quantity should shown in arraylist 2 .

Exisiting code for extracting data as txt from PDF.

PDFBoxReadFromFile.java

```js
package pdfboxreadfromfile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.io.*;

public class PDFBoxReadFromFile {

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PDFManager pdfManager = new PDFManager();
    pdfManager.setFilePath("C:\\Users\\34\\Documents\\test.pdf");
    try {
      String text = pdfManager.toText();
      System.out.println(text);
      File file = new File("C:/Users/34/eclipse-workspace/pdfboxreadfromfile/file.txt");
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
      pw.println(text);
      pw.close();



    } catch (IOException ex) {
      //System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
      Logger.getLogger(PDFBoxReadFromFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }
  }

}
```

PDFManager.Java

```js
package pdfboxreadfromfile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class PDFManager {
  private PDFParser parser;
  private PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
  private PDDocument pdDoc;
  private COSDocument cosDoc;

  private String Text;
  private String filePath;
  private File file;

  public PDFManager() {

  }

  public String toText() throws IOException {
    this.pdfStripper = null;
    this.pdDoc = null;
    this.cosDoc = null;

    file = new File(filePath);
    parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")); // update for PDFBox V 2.0

    parser.parse();
    cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
    pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
    pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();
    pdfStripper.setStartPage(0);
    pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());
    Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
    return Text;
  }

  public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
  }

  public PDDocument getPdDoc() {
    return pdDoc;
  }

}
```

java

Comment: How typical is your image? Are all purchase orders you have to process like this, are they generated by the same program? Or may they look different, being generated by different programs, just similar to your example?

Comment: @mkl mostly yes

Comment: *mostly* as in "most documents are exactly like that" or in "the documents are mostly like that"?

Comment: The documents are mostly like that.. .

Comment: An obvious way to extract your header information would be either to use the exact coordinates of rectangles in which each datum respectively can be expected. Another would be to retrieve the text and identify each datum by specific keywords. To determine which of those ways works in your case, though, one needs to know what kind of documents to expect exactly, in particular whether the information can be recognized by either coordinates or keywords.

Comment: @mkl would well to try with corindates and keywords with different array list. If you can share any sample codings for the same would be helpful....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214524/discussion-between-leace-and-mkl).

Comment: Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1.55,6.84,0.61,0.19); not accepting
error in The constructor Rectangle(double, double, double, double) is undefined

Comment: You should look at the example using `Rectangle2D.Float`. Other than that, though, your numbers look very small. Remember most dimensions in PDFs are handled in Points (72pt =1in). Thus, a width of 0.61 and a height of 0.19 very likely are too small for text.

Comment: @mkl whats is alternative way of extracting specific area text ? in header i need extract three box details which close to 5 to 7 characters each. example date "5/10/2010"..

Comment: Also its very weired i am able to bring specific area by "Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(55, 290, 225, 17) where as its real value  for X-1.55,Y-6.84,W-0.49,H-0.10